# How to switch the language by code in flutter-web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-intl

I am having problems switching the language in a flutter-web application.
I added the required dependencies to the `package.yml`.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.16.1

  flutter_localizations:
      sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  intl_translation: ^0.17.9
```

Then I initialized the `intl` stuff in the MaterialApp.

```
 [...]
 child: MaterialApp(
        localizationsDelegates: [
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          S.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: S.delegate.supportedLocales,
        [...]
```

Here is the code I expect to change the locale.

```
                Text(S.of(context).language),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("deutsch"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    S.load(Locale('de'));
                  },
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("englisch"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    S.load(Locale('en'));
                  },
```

Here are two `arb` files containing the translation.

```
{
    "language": "Deutsch"
}
```

```
{
    "language": "English"
}
```

Everything compiles and I can access the `S.of(context)` classes. I am sure I missed something. Since the switching of the language doesn't work either if I start in the Android Emulator.

Switching the system locale in the emulator changes the language.

I would appreciate any help or hints.